# Adding fields to URL using Retrofit

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I am building an Android APP where I use the Internet Game Database API through Mashape market place. I am using Retrofit for the get requests and getting data from the API requires an API key.

I got it to work but the API only return game ids and I want the game names and other information, but I am not sure how to add the fields. This is how Mashape query it:

```
    HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get("https://igdbcom-internet-game-database-v1.p.mashape.com/games/?fields=name%2Crelease_dates")
.header("X-Mashape-Key", "API KEY HERE")
.header("Accept", "application/json")
.asString();
```

and this is my Retrofit Interface

```
public interface GamesAPIService {

    @GET("/games/")
    Call<List<GamesResponse>> gameList(@Query("mashape-key") String apikey);

}
```

I tried to use this

```
@GET("/games/?fields=name,release_dates")
```

But no luck, I also tried with @Field but didn't work either. Any ideas? Thanks.

Edit: Just to clarify when I add the `"?fields=name,release_dates"` I get 401 Unauthorized Error.

Comment: Why do you have `@Query("mashape-key") String apikey`? You have no `?mashape-key=...` in the URL... The key needs to be a header, not a query param.

Comment: I tried @Header to pass the apikey or in the activity itself as ".addHeader" and it never worked, but it worked that way for some reason so I kept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I think you need to add mashape key to all your request.

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("X-Mashape-Key", "API_KEY_HERE")
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://igdbcom-internet-game-database-v1.p.mashape.com")
    .client(httpClient)
    .build();
```

And then this is information query.

```
public interface GamesAPIService {
    @GET("/games")
    Call<List<GamesResponse>> gameList(@Query("fields") String value);
}
```

And last thing for calling.

```
GamesAPIService gamesAPIService = retrofit.create(GamesAPIService.class);

Call<List<GamesResponse>> call = gamesAPIService.gameList("name,release_dates");
if (call!=null){
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GamesResponse>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<GamesResponse>> call, Response<List<GamesResponse>> response) {
            // handle success
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            // handle failure
        }
   });
}
```